How to extract from multiple zip files only the csv files whose name starts with a specific string of characters in r?
Let's consider a folder myfile containing more than a hundred zip files (z001.zip, z002.zip, z003.zip ...) each always including 4 distinct csv files whose names always start with these three letters aaa..., bbb..., ccc..., ddd..., the rest of the name varying from one zip to another.
How to extract in myfile all the csv files whose name starts with bbb... but not the other 3?
Note: a similar question was answered here but it does not answer the present issue since the extraction was for a single zip file (not for multiple zips), and the pattern sought was the .csv extension (not the starting string of the csv name).
Thanks for help

brute force: unzip with lapply and grep those containing "[bbb]" (with lapply).

Do the csv files all have different names or may they be overwritten when they are extracted all at once?

@Andre, yes, except the first 3 letters, the rest of csv files names varies from one zip to another

Basically something like sapply(list.files(pattern=".*zip$"), \(x) sapply(unzip(x, list=T)$Name, \(y) ifelse(grepl("^bbbb", y), unzip(x, files=y), NA)))...

maybe: `library(plyr) # get all the zip files
zipF <- list.files(path = "/your/path/here/", pattern = "*.zip", full.names = TRUE)
unzip all your files
ldply(.data = zipF, .fun = unzip, exdir = outDir)
get the csv files
csv_files <- list.files(path = outDir, pattern = "bbb")
read the csv files
my_data <- ldply(.data = csv_files, .fun = read.csv)
#or this would also work: bbd_data <- lapply(aa, function(x)read.table(x, header=T, fill=T))
#to rbind them together afterwards this might work (if needed)
bbb_bind <- do.call("rbind", my_data)`

Andre, thanks but it does not work because of ''.
Shizzle, thanks but it extracts all the 4 csv from all zip, which takes too many time. I would like to extract only 'bbb...' csv.

Because of \(x)? Which R version are you sitting on? Update, or replace \(x) and \(y) with function(x) and function(y) if R version < 4.x.y.

@Friede, you're right, thanks! It works perfectly after updating R to 4.4.1 version. You could propose it in response.
